# Rails number_field that displays whole numbers if nothing to right of decimal

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my rails view, I've got the following code for a number field:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <%= f.number_field :percent, step: :any, :required => true, :class => 'percent-field', :placeholder => "Percent" %>
    <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My database is set to save these values as decimals, with a precision of 5 and a scale of 2. This is from my schema:

```
t.decimal "percent", precision: 5, scale: 2
```

If a user types a whole number in the number input field and saves that value, when they go back and try to edit that value it is showing a number with a decimal and one zero to the right of the decimal. So "30" becomes "30.0".

How can I get the input field edit view to display only the whole number, without a decimal, in cases where nothing is added to the right of the decimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can pass previous value to :value and give it the format like this code below

```
<div class="input-group">
    <%= f.number_field :percent, step: :any, :required => true, :class => 'percent-field', :placeholder => "Percent", :value => number_with_precision(f.object.percent,precision: 2,  strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %>
    <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strip_insignificant_zeros helper as explained [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html).

It's basically converting your float to integer if ending is .0